# FPS controller animation on trigger Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I have a tv and an fps controller. The thing I'm trying to get working is: every time the tv is pressed by the mouse it spawns the fps in front of the tv in a specific location and then plays the animation.

I have got the spawn of the FPS to work however, once the user is spawned in front of the tv it does not play the animation.

The FPS controller has an Animator applied in the inspector whilst the tv has a script which is supposed to play the animation. The code is below:

```
if (tv)
{
    person.transform.position = new Vector3((float)-3.69, (float)1.81, (float)-4.83);
    person.transform.Rotate((float)1.266, (float)5.888, 0);

    Vector3 destination = new Vector3(83, 60, 0);
    person.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, destination, Time.deltaTime);

    anim.enabled = true;
}
```

However ani does not work, any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is this block called? In `Update`? And what is `anim`?

Comment: I'm still confused about what exactly you are doing .. `Animator`, `Animation` .. how are they connected/configured? and what are you animating there?

Comment: I am running an Animator component within the FPS controller Inspector and on the TV C# script I've got a variable called Animator which references that which is in the FPS controller